# limit on the length of an identifier in C

Tags: c, uniqueidentifier, identifier

It is said that two distinct identifiers must differ in their first 31 characters irrespective of their total length.Why there is a limit on the length of an identifier(31 characters) in C ?

Comment: The standard only places [lower bounds](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1) for implementations to follow, probably to ensure lowest common denominator in current architecture. But it also [encourages](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note18) implementations to far exceed them whenever possible.

Comment: you better read official documentation for research.

Comment: Prior to C99 the requirement was only 6 characters. That made for fun times when working with linkers that did not exceed the minimum requirement

Answer (score 0):

This limit is to make internal bookkeeping simpler, so that a compiler can safely allocate no more than 32 characters (31 + the null terminator) for a variable name (like there is a limit on surname length in different paper forms). The exact limit is arbitrary, just small enough for memory and large enough for programmers.

Also because on some systems the linking is a separate step from the C compiler system, and object files not written in C may be linked. These can have limits on identifier length.

Update: The thing is it's possible to make one program consisting of several parts written in different languages (e.g. a function may be already written in Fortran and called from the main C code). Other languages may impose different limits on variable lengths (an artificial example: if identifies `abcdef` and `abcdef1` are considered referring to the same function in Fortran code, it should be so in C code). An illustration using the surname example: local authorities may be able to process names with a large length or in a local language, but the requirements of federal authorities may be more strict.

Comment: Thank you understood the answer.Can you please elaborate how linking forces limit on the length of identifier.

Comment: That was the addition of Malcolm McLean who edited the post. I've updated the answer.